# Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jndi

I'm getting an error when I try to start my Tomcat server.

I get the following error message:

> Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

```
Apr 08, 2018 6:05:09 PM org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl cleanUp
WARNING: Failed to retrieve JNDI naming context for container [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/project]] so no cleanup was performed for that container
javax.naming.NamingException: No naming context bound to this class loader
    at org.apache.naming.ContextBindings.getClassLoader(ContextBindings.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.cleanUp(NamingResourcesImpl.java:992)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.NamingResourcesImpl.stopInternal(NamingResourcesImpl.java:975)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1040)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.destroyInternal(ContainerBase.java:1040)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:604)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:879)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:483)
```

Comment: show us your server.xml and web.xml entries

Comment: Can your web application work fine on another Tomcat?